# IAP restore returns error code 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storekit

When a user tries to restore his purchases in my app, it returns error code 2 when it really shouldn't.

It can be started by either actually restoring (`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`) or purchasing the non-consumable again.

The app than shows the StoreKit alert "This In-App Purchase has already been bought" but instead of the transactionState in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` being `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` it is `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` with error code 2 and error message "Cannot connect to iTunes Store."

Also, this does not happen for all IAPs. There is one I know of, but it is also the most important one in the app.

There are [more people](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/192546#192546) with this problem, but without a solution. Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue? I'm seeing it happen one or two times per day